# List Payouts of stripe Account

Tags: ruby, stripe-payments

According to [Stripe Payout API](https://stripe.com/docs/api#list_payouts)
I need to retrieve all payouts of a destination, So i made this request:

```
def all_payouts(external_account)
   return Stripe::Payout.list(
      :destination => external_account
   )
end
```

from the API I tried to send the external_account(like "ba_XXXX") but it keeps returning

`No such external account: ba_XXXX` while testing it using Postman, I checked the external_account but it is exists on stripe.

Any help?

Comment: Are you trying to list payouts on *your* stripe account, or on a *connected account* --- if the latter you'll need to authenticate with the stripe account header, so the call is being made on the connected account. https://stripe.com/docs/connect/authentication#stripe-account-header

Comment: Yes this was my problem, I have used the `Authentication via the Stripe-Account header` way.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since this is a common enough question and easy to miss that you solved it in the comments, here's the correct code to do this.

When trying to list payouts on a connected account, you have to make the API request authenticating as this account. You would pass the platform's Secret API key along with the connected account's id in the `Stripe-Account` [header](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/authentication#authentication-via-the-stripe-account-header). In Ruby, the code would look like this:

```
payouts = Stripe::Payout.list(
  {:destination => external_account},
  {:stripe_account => "acct_XXXXXX"},
)
```

Comment: Yes, I added the header and it worked.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: +1 This same principle is applicable to all languages, including PHP (the one I'm using for this exact same thing). It's worth noting that the Payout _parameters_ need to be an *a separate array* to the `stripe_account` authentication; so [pseudocode] `Payout.list({'destination': 'ba_xxxx', 'limit': 3}, {'stripe_account': 'acct_xxxx'})` - this caught me out when I initially put `stripe_account` as one of the regular arguments.